# CSV import into mysql imports empty rows

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, import

I've read a lot about importing excel as csv into mysql with php. I haven't done it before so be aware that there may be stupid mistakes.

I want to start the import from the second row and I've checked what is the delimeter that my file has - it's `;` .

My php:

```
            if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

            $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];

            $extensions = array("csv");
            $filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if (in_array($filetype, $extensions)) {
                $file = fopen($filename, "r");
                $count = 0;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                    $count++;
                    if ($count>1) {                         
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO Events(TitleBG) VALUES (?)";
                        $stmtCommit = $db -> prepare($sql);
                        $stmtCommit -> bind_param('s', $data[0]);
                        $stmtCommit -> execute();
                        $stmtCommit -> close();
                    }           
                } // while
                fclose($file);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that it imports thousands of empty rows. Can someone point me to the problem? Thank you in advance and sorry if the question was asked before(I couldn't find that problem).

Comment: it shouldn't import ANYTHING. `['file']['name']` is the filename of the file on the CLIENT. it has NOTHING to do with the filename php stored the upload in on the server. that's `['tmp_name']`. Your fopen should have failed, your fgetcsv should then ALSO fail, and skip all of the database stuff.

Comment: Either check if the $data[0] is empty; or use [SPLFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php)'s fgetcsv() method, because you can tell it to ignore empty lines

Comment: and note that having your prepare/bind inside the loop negates the purpose of having prepared statements. you prepare/bind a statement **ONCE**, then simply re-use in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the prepared statement thing. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @MarcB I removed the prepare/bind part and changed to `tmp_name` but  only the first row was inserted. I'll check everything again but I can't see the problem

Comment: what's the point of that `$count` stuff? if you're trying to skip over a row of the csv, there's clearer ways, like doing a separate `$row_to_skip = fgetcsv()` before entering the loop. Plus, don't close() the statement until you're doing with it. prepare/bind/close must all be outside the loop.

Comment: That's the point but I found only this way. I tried your way and works perfect. Thank you!